# How to get result of FutureBuilder from the parent FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter

The entry point is `_processError` function. I expect to get a widdet there. And this `_processError` runs from a parent FutureBuilder.
Then another Future builder should be executed, at least I think it should... But it seems there is no result from there. Whats wrong with it?

```
FutureBuilder<List<ShortLetter>>(
  future: fetchMessages(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ShortLetter>> snapshot) {
    ...
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return _processError(snapshot, context); // I want to get a widget when an error happens
    ...
  },
);

Future<bool> checkConnection() async {
  debugPrint('---checkConnection---');
  var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
  ...
  // and returs true or false
}

Widget _processError(AsyncSnapshot snapshot, BuildContext context) {
  var errorType = snapshot.error.runtimeType;
  debugPrint('AllMessagesView, snapshot error: $errorType');
  debugPrint(snapshot.error.toString());
  if (errorType == TimeoutException) {
    debugPrint('0000000000000000');
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // there is any output in console from the FutureBuilder below
    // but checkConnection() was executed   
      
    FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: checkConnection(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {     
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          debugPrint('11111111111111 snapshot data: ${snapshot.data}');
          if (snapshot.data == true) {
            ...
          }
          ...
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          debugPrint('2222222222222');
          ...
        } else {
          debugPrint('Error. This should not happen.');
          ...
        }
      },
    );
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

here is a sample console output and any result from the second FutureBuilder

```
I/flutter (10556): AllMessagesView, snapshot error: TimeoutException
I/flutter (10556): TimeoutException after 0:00:10.000000: Future not completed
I/flutter (10556): 0000000000000000
I/flutter (10556): ---checkConnection---
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent FutureBuilder is already been processed, I think we don't need to pass `Async` data.

This demo widget may help.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<int> parentF() async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 4);
  }

  Future<String> childF(int sec) async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: sec), () => "got the child");
  }

  Widget childFB(final data) {
    print(data.runtimeType);
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: childF(4),
        builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
            ? Text("${snapshot.data!} parent data: $data ")
            : const Text("loading second child"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder(
          future: parentF(),
          builder: (context, parentSnapshot) {
            return parentSnapshot.hasData
                ? FutureBuilder<String>(
                    future: childF(3),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return snapshot.hasData
                          ? Text(
                              "${snapshot.data!} parent data: ${parentSnapshot.data} ")
                          : const Text("loading child");
                    },
                  )
                : const Text("loading parent");
          },
        ),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: parentF(),
          builder: (context, parentSnapshot) {
            return parentSnapshot.hasData
                ? childFB(parentSnapshot
                    .data) // it already have normal data, not async
                : const Text("loading parent");
          },
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```